# LINQ GroupBy List<>

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a straightforward LINQ query that is attempting to perform a GroupBy where one of the items in the statements is a `List<string>.`

```
var viewModel = reports
       .GroupBy(c => new { c.Id, c.PetList })
       .Select(g => new ArmReportModel
        {
            PetList = g.Key.PetList,
            Pets = g.Count()
        });
```

Prior to this statement I am executing my EF repository method which ultimately calls a method to create the PetList above.

If I remove the PetList from the `GroupBy()` it works as expected.  Is there something I must do in order to group by a `List<string>` type?

Comment: How do you group by a list?  If you have a class that defines "equality" for two pet lists then you can pass that to `GroupBy` - otherwise reference equality will be used by default.

Comment: So similar to a custom IComparable?

Comment: Yes - create a class that implements [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx) and pass that to `GroupBy`.  Make sure you follow the [guidelines for implementing `GetHashCode`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode/) as well.

Comment: That will only work for LINQ to Objects, and not EF. Grouping by list seems bad in general. Can you describe your scenario a little more?

Comment: When grabbing the data prior to this I am doing a call to my repository and then a .Select(Map) in which the Map function populates the List<string> for purposes of displaying to the user.  The data in the list is based on data from the repository.  In my case it is a list of classification conditions relative to each row on the final report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would assume that `Id` is an identifier, and hence any two `c` with the same `Id` is in fact the same and has the same `PetList`. As such we can `GroupBy` just the `Id` and get the `PetList` another way:

```
var viewModel = reports
  .GroupBy(c => c.Id)
  .Select(g => new ArmReportModel
  {
    PetList = g.First().PetList, // Might need FirstOrDefault() with some providers
    Pets = g.Count()
  });
```

Barring that, I'd want to first make sure I could use an `IEqualityComparer<T>` with the `GroupBy`. If the provider allows for that, then no problem. Otherwise I'd start with:

```
reports.Select(c => new {c.Id, c.PetList}).AsEnumerable()
```

This retrieves the minimum necessary from the provider into memory, so that the linq-to-objects provider can be used from that point on.

I need to be able to define an `IEqualityComparer<T>` for some `T`, so I stop using anonymous types:

```
private class IdAndList
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public List<string> PetList { get; set; }
}

private class ReportIdAndPetListComparer : IEqualityComparer<IdAndList>
{
  public bool Equals(IdAndList x, IdAndList y)
  {
    if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
    if (x == null || y == null) return false;
    if (x.Id != y.Id) return false;
    if (x.PetList == null) return y.PetList == null;
    if (y.PetList == null) return false;
    int count = x.PetList.Count;
    if (y.PetList.Count != count) return false;
    for (int i = 0; i != count; ++i)
      if (x.PetList[i] != y.PetList[i]) return false;
    return true;
  }

  public int GetHashCode(IdAndList obj)
  {
    int hash = obj.Id;
    if (obj.PetList != null)
      foreach (string pet in obj.PetList)
        hash = hash * 31 + pet.GetHashCode();
    return hash;
  }
}
```

Some of the tests for null `PetList`s can be removed if you know that's not possible.

Now:

```
var viewModel = reports.Select(c => new IdAndList{c.Id, c.PetList}).AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(c => c, new ReportIdAndPetListComparer())
    .Select(g => new ArmReportModel
    {
        PetList = g.Key.PetList,
        Pets = g.Count()
    });
```

Or if the provider can't deal with constructing the `IdAndPetList` type, then:

```
var viewModel = reports.Select(c => new {c.Id, c.PetList})
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(c => new IdAndList{c.Id, c.PetList})
    .GroupBy(c => c, new ReportIdAndPetListComparer())
    .Select(g => new ArmReportModel
    {
        PetList = g.Key.PetList,
        Pets = g.Count()
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the code!  I'll check this morning, but wouldn't "g.First().PetList" just give the first item in the list rather than the first row prior to the GroupBy?

Comment: No, it will give you the list in the first item in the group. (As said, if that is only correct if every report with the same `Id` inherently has the same list, otherwise it won't be and the longer part of the answer becomes necessary).

Comment: This was perfect.  Thanks for providing the examples for usage as well.  Very helpful.  I had to tweak it slightly for the Select() because it was complaining about 'object notation' but it was otherwise precisely what I needed.  Thanks again!

Comment: Ah good. If it needed a bit of tweaking, then hopefully that resulted in your gaining a better idea of just how it worked than if it hadn't :)